# In package `crosstalk`, are there have function `bsrows()` and `rows+cols` mixed?

Tags: plotly, crosstalk

In package `crosstalk`, there is function `bscols()` make plots align in a row. But I cant't find function `bsrows()` and `rows+cols` mixed , is any package have such function? Thanks!

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyr)
library(crosstalk)

m <- gather(mtcars, variable, value, -vs)
msd <- highlight_key(m, ~variable)
gg <- ggplot(msd, aes(factor(vs), value)) + 
  geom_jitter(alpha = 0.3)

bscols(
  widths = c(11, 6, 6),
  filter_select("id", "Select a variable", msd, ~variable, multiple = FALSE),
  ggplotly(gg, dynamicTicks = "y") %>% layout(margin = list(l = 30)),
  plot_ly(msd, x = ~jitter(vs), y = ~value) %>% add_markers(alpha = 0.3)
)
```

Comment: Have you had any success in figuring this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was searching for the same thing until realizing that 12 is the maximum number of columns in `crosstalk::bscols()`. This means that you can put every widget on next row just by specifying `widths = 12` for the previous one. By adjusting widths you can adjust both columns and when new rows are introduces. It is probably not the interface you were hoping for but it works. Here is an example with your widgests on separate rows (I added `htmltools` to use breaks):

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyr)
library(crosstalk)
library(htmltools)

m <- gather(mtcars, variable, value, -vs)
msd <- highlight_key(m, ~variable)
gg <- ggplot(msd, aes(factor(vs), value)) + 
  geom_jitter(alpha = 0.3)

suppressWarnings({
  bscols(
    widths = c(12, 12, 12),
    filter_select("id", "Select a variable", msd, ~variable, multiple = FALSE),
    htmltools::br(),
    ggplotly(gg, dynamicTicks = "y") %>% layout(margin = list(l = 30)),
    htmltools::br(),
    plot_ly(msd, x = ~jitter(vs), y = ~value) %>% add_markers(alpha = 0.3)
  )
})
```